# Android: How to send interface from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-activity, interface

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void aMethod();
}
```

My custom Object:

```
public class MyObject {

    private Context context;
    private MyInterface inter;

    public MyObject(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.inter = (MyInterface) this.context;
        inter.aMethod();
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyObject my = new MyObject(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void aMethod() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here, inside MyObject constructor i can get the interface from the context and then communicate with the Activity.

**But how can i send interface from one activity to another ?

I need to call a method inside Activity1 from Activity2

Is there a way like this ?**

**Note:** i don't want to use fragment.

Comment: Is your problem solved or do you need further assistance? Please don't forget to accept the answer which helped you most!

Comment: stucked with the same problem thanks for questioning this :)

Comment: You can't ... and you shouldn't ... obviously you should be aware that in worst case scenario **there is only one Activity which is alive!** ... Instead you should use normal startActivityForResult/onActivityResult

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First and foremost, this is very bad:

```
this.inter = (MyInterface) this.context;
```

If you pass a context into the constructor which does not implement your interface your application will crash and it's easy to make such a mistake. So you see, this is very error prone, instead implement it like this:

```
public class MyObject {

    private Context context;
    private MyInterface inter;

    public MyObject(Context context, MyInterface inter) {
        this.context = context;
        this.inter =  inter;
        inter.aMethod();
    }
}
```

This way it's much safer, and cleaner.

---

To send the `Object` to another `Activity` make sure it implements `Serializable` like this:

```
public interface MyInterface extends Serializable {
    public void aMethod();
}
```

And now you can just add the interface as an extra to the `Intent` which starts the other `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("interface", inter);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the `OtherActivity` you can get the `Object` from the `Intent` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    MyInterface inter = (MyInterface) intent.getSerializableExtra("interface");

    ...
}
```

---

## EDIT:

When you do something like this in your `Activity` you are creating an anonymous class:

```
OnCreateListener inter = new OnCreateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onObjCreate() {
        Log.d("pltk", "dfgbfdgh");
    }
};
```

The thing about such an anonymous class is that they are not static, meaning you can still access methods and variables from the class in which this listener is nested. Internally the reason for this is that this new class keeps a reference to the instance of the class which created it, in your case the enclosing `Activity`. This is a great thing and we use it all the time for `OnClickListener` etc. But in your case it is a problem because you want to send this `Object` to another `Activity`. The internal reference to the old `Activity` keeps it from being serialised and that is a good thing. If you could just send an `Object` like that you would create memory leaks like crazy because of all the old references which the garbage collector cannot collect.

The solution is pretty simple, you can either define the class in its own file or you can make the class static. Static in this context means that the class is essentially treated like it were in it's own separate file and therefore cannot access the instance of the enclosing class.

So to summarise what you have to do is either keep the class nested and define it static like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private static class OnCreateListenerImpl implements OnCreateListener {

        @Override
        public void onObjCreate() {
            Log.d("pltk", "dfgbfdgh");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_palatok);

        OnCreateListener inter = new OnCreateListenerImpl();
        Intent in = new Intent(Palatok.this, SecondActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("ob", inter);
        startActivity(in);
    }
}
```

Or you can move the implementation in its own separate file:

```
public class OnCreateListenerImpl implements OnCreateListener {

    @Override
    public void onObjCreate() {
        Log.d("pltk", "dfgbfdgh");
    }
}
```

Although the reason why you would want to send an `OnCreateListener` to another `Activity` still eludes me, this should solve your problem.

I hope I could help and if you have any further questions feel free to ask!

Comment: Edit it into your question, don't link to it... Anyway the error is right there in the log: `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.palatok.Palatok`. Is `com.example.palatok.Palatok` an `Activity` of yours?

Comment: I thought so :) I will edit my answer with a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. One more question. If i write the class in separate file then i wouldn't be able to access variables inside Activity, so i always need to make static class, is it good practice to write static class inside activity ?

Comment: Either way you cannot access the `Activity` instance. Having a nested static class is ok. It always depends on the specific situation if its good practice or not. In your case it is pretty weird that you are trying to pass a listener to a separate `Activity`. I would worry more about that than some static nested class.

Comment: If i create anonymous class(interface) and send it to non-Activity class will it cause problem ?I already used many anonymous class and passed them to non-Activity class so that they can communicate with Activity ? Will it be a problem later(memory leak or anything like that)

Comment: No, memory leaks can only really be created if threading is involved, for example in an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`. It's the reason why you are supposed to work with `WeakReferences` in `AsyncTasks`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I Accepted your answer

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for this solution

Comment: **Tis is terrible solution do not use it!** It obviously doesnt work: 1st lets replace `Log.d` with `setTitle` ... 2nd lest enable "Don't keep activities " ... In worst case scenario only one Activity is alive ... and backing to previous Activity will(in such case) obviously create new instance ...

Comment: ...also your code after edit in worst case scenario is just equal to calling `new  OnCreateListenerImpl.onObjCreate();` from second activity ... which makes passing interface via Intent usless.

Comment: There is no way this can work, since the `Serializable` interface cannot be passed around like that, due to the fact that it's parent class might not be serializable. It'll most likely result in a crash.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible but such kind of Activity <-> Activity interraction will cause memory leaks. You should use LocalBroadcastManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) instead.

Comment: I just need to access the private variable of Activity1 from Activity2, that's it.

Comment: but y do u want to access a private variable ??

Comment: @palatok Did you try SharedPreferences?

Comment: i have a large object inside Activity1, other activities need the data from this object