# Parcelable class with an interface member variable

Tags: android, parcelable

Let's assume that I have this small class:

```java
public Class A {
    private int mA = 0;
    private MyInterface mInterface = null;

    public interface MyInterface {
        public void test();
    }

    public void setA(int a) { mA = a; }
    public void setInterface(MyInterface i) { mInterface = i; }
}
```

OK. Now, how I can make it `Parcelable`?
Adding `mA` to a `Parcel` is easy, but how I can Parcel interface `mInterface`? I have not found any examples for adding interface to a `Parcel`.

Regards

UPDATE:
I should say that I have been able to do this as a `Seializable` class. But I like to know how this can be done in `Parcelable`.

Examples for `Serializable` can be found here: [Android: How to send interface from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780000/android-how-to-send-interface-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: because you cannot do that, you can add only things that `Parcelable` class supports

Comment: @pskink I have not seen anything about what `Parcelable` class supports. In addition, I don't think what I need to do is too abnormal. A simple example is passing an array of this class to a `Fragment` with different callback methods for each array member(Different callback routines).

Comment: so why do you need `Parcelable` at all?

Comment: @pskink Because for passing an object or class in some situations (e.g. passing to `Fragment` via `Bundle`), they need to get serialized. So I need to make my class `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend your interface by Parcelable interface.
E.g :

```
public interface MyInterface extends Parcelable
```

Comment: And then how I need to write my `WritetoParcel()` and `MyInterface(Parcel in)` to store and restore this member interface?

Comment: Correct, even if you are implementing your own interface only.