# How do I enable a button from another activity using Java?

Tags: java, android

**activity_levels.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/level2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="130dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="198dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:text="2"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

**Levels.java**

```
public class Levels extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_levels);
    }
}
```

**activity_level_one_result.xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Next Level"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:onClick="nextLevel"/>
```

**LevelOneResult.java**

```
public class LevelOneResult extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_one_result);
    }

    public void nextLevel(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Levels.class));
        // enable the button here
    }
}
```

I want to enable the level 2 button from `activity_levels.xml` file. I want it to be enabled by using Java in `LevelOneResult.java`. As you can see above, I've added a comment section to where I want to put the code in.

Comment: user observer patterns or interface

Comment: put both activity code here and please describe more in detail

Comment: I've added both activity code and explained in more detail.

Comment: pass a Bundle to that Intent, where you set that you want to enable that button (I'd actually say, "where you put the second activity in a state where that button should be enabled", to be more precise), and receive the Bundle from the second activity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24780184/4332049 I think this answer solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `interface` in your LevelOneResult.java like below,I explain in the comment in code:

```
public class LevelOneResult extends AppCompatActivity {

    OnCompleteListener mListener;
    //create an listener
    public  interface OnCompleteListener {
         void onComplete(boolean enableOrNot);
    }
    //attach the listener in the activity
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            this.mListener = (OnCompleteListener)activity;
        }
        catch (final ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnCompleteListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_one_result);


    }

    public void nextLevel(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Levels.class));
        // enable the button here

        here trigger the listener
        //true means enable
         mListener.onComplete(true);
    }
}
```

In your `Levels.java`,you need to implements  the `interface`,get the data from the interface `onComplete()` and do your stuff

```
public class Levels extends AppCompatActivity implements LevelOneResult.OnCompleteListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_levels);
    }

    public void onComplete(boolean enableOrNot ) {
        // after the action in LevelOne
        // the boolean trigger here..

        //here the boolean is true,which u set in levelOneJava
        if(enableOrNot){
            //then do your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```