# Activity not update with new Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i have an ActivityA that is started with an ID that is passed in the intent. In another thread, a pop-up is determined when an ID is received. Then you can open ActivityA with this ID. When the ActivityA is opened, the ID that you submitted is used.

But if the ActivityA is open, the ID not updated with the new submitted ID?

ActivityA:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_detail);
    getId();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getId();
}

private void getId(){
    long id = getIntent().getLongExtra("ID", 0L);
}
```

The pop-up:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.putExtra("ID", newId);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thank you for anser!

Comment: Where are you using that pop-up? Pop-up ? Why are you calling your start intent that way?  And where was newId assigned?

Comment: Override onNewIntent().

Answer (score 1):

Once ActivityA is opened the Extra values are set and are not changeable.

You do have a few options:

1. Start a new copy of ActivityA - maybe the worse solution depending on the design and this isn't what I would suggest but you could do it.
2. Since you mentioned that the ID was being calculated by a thread, a better solution would be to implement an interface that ActivityA implements and have the thread call the interface method which in turn can update the ID.  Keeping in mind that if, as a result of changing the ID results in accessing UI elements you must do that on the main thread.

this link should help:  [android-how-to-send-interface-from-one-activity-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780000/android-how-to-send-interface-from-one-activity-to-another), it's the same principal as I mention above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've put me on the right track:

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent)
}

Is Works!